# Javascript Timer is not accurate

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, countdown

I'm running countdown timer in Webpage , But it's not running properly sometimes . It's runs 20-30 seconds more or less . When I move to different tabs , It runs 8-10 seconds more . Is there any way to run timer accurately ?

```
 <script>
    var display<?=$j ?> = document.querySelector('#time<?= $j ?>');
    startTimer(<?= $differenceInSeconds?>, display<?=$j ?>,"<?= $res_tutor[$i]['student_id_fk'] ?>","row<?= $j ?>");
 </script>
function startTimer(duration, display,student_id,row)
{
    var start = Date.now(),
        diff,
        minutes,
        seconds;
    var stop;
    function timer() {
        // get the number of seconds that have elapsed since 
        // startTimer() was called
        diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);

        // does the same job as parseInt truncates the float

        hours = (diff / 3600) | 0;
        minutes = (diff / 60)-(hours*60) | 0;
        seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;


        hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent =hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds; 
        if (diff <= 0) {
            // add one second so that the count down starts at the full duration
            // example 05:00 not 04:59
            start = Date.now() + 1000;
        }
        if((minutes == 0) && (seconds == 0))
        {
            // display.textContent ="Expired";
            //jQuery("#"+row+"  td:nth-child(2) a").css("pointer-events","none");

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: 'ajax_form_handler.php',
                type: 'GET',
                data: {'access':'true','action':'getUpdatedTime','student_id':student_id},
                success: function(data) {

                    if(data>0)
                    {
                        console.log("duration is "+data);
                    duration=data;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(data<=0)
                        {
                            duration=0; 

                        }
                         display.textContent ="Timeout";
                        jQuery("#"+row+"  td:nth-child(2) a").css("pointer-events","none");
                          console.log(">>>"+data);  
                          clearTimeout(stop);

                    }

                     console.log(">>"+data);                         
                },
                error: function(e)
                {
                    //alert("Some error occurred and request could not be completed.");
                    jQuery("#"+holder).html(ACTION_ERROR).fadeIn(100);
                }




        });
        }
        stop=setTimeout(timer, 1000);
            }   


    // we don't want to wait a full second before the timer starts
    timer();
    //setInterval(timer, 1000);

}
```